# Unable to import more than 200 records by using feeds module in drupal 7

Tags: mysql, drupal-7, feed, php-5.3

Help us to overcome with this problem to unable to import more than 200 records.

I have changed in php.ini which is given as follows.

```
   max_exec_time    1000
   memory_limit     1024 
   post_max_size    22M
```

and then restarted the Apache server at all. But did't get the solution.

I have tried by updating the settings.php (sites/default/settings.php) as adding

```
$conf['feeds_process_limit'] = 2000;
```

Please help us as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Clear Drupal cache after changing that setting.

https://drupal.org/node/42055